# After migrating from .net core 3.1 to .net 6.0 MapVersionedODataRoutes method under Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions not available

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, odata, .net-6.0

Currently I am using .netcore 3.1 project. Started migrating it to .net6.0

Below code is currently implemented in .netcore3.1

```
app.UseMvc(b =>
            {
                b.MapVersionedODataRoutes("odata-versioned", "odata", edmModels);
            });
```

After migrating the framework to .net6.0 and I am getting error that MapVersionedODataRoutes is not available.
Are there a breaking changes? What is the new way of implementing the same.

Got stuck as the MapVersionedODataRoutes was not available

Comment: Have you installed the Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Versioning package inside the .net 6?

Comment: No I have not installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Versioning. I have installed Asp.Versioning.OData.ApiExplorer.  Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Versioning has dependencis for Microsfot.ASPNetCore.Odata < 8

Comment: I have updated Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData to 8.0.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to implement API versioning? In OData 8.0.11, you can implement it by `AddRouteComponents`:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddOData(opt => opt.AddRouteComponents("v{version}", edmModel));
```

For more details, you can refer to [this link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/api-versioning-extension-with-asp-net-core-odata-8/).

In addition, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Versioning` contains a `MapVersionedODataRoute` property, which may help you.